# DataSpell throws error while PyCharm and Spyder don´t - using the same python interpreter

Tags: pycharm, dataspell, wrds

I want to load and run the [wrds](https://pypi.org/project/wrds/) library in DataSpell. I used pip to install version 3.1.6.

The wrds library works like a charm in PyCharm and Spyder.

However, when using DataSpell, I get the below error. I use the same Anaconda interpreter for all three (Spyder 5.4.3, PyCharm, Dataspell). I also deleted all files from the `.idea` folder in my project folder. And nothing works.

It is annoying, because DataSpell works better than PyCharm in scientific mode and Spyder is kinda feature poor.

```
import os
import wrds # https://matteocourthoud.github.io/post/wrds/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martien/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-254b32a46b05>", line 1, in <module>
    import wrds # https://matteocourthoud.github.io/post/wrds/
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martien/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/DataSpell/ch-0/233.13135.105/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/../../wrds.py", line 21, in <module>
    if os.name=='nt':
       ^^
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Maybe it has to do with this line which appears at the top of the console when I run these two import commands (`import os` and `import wrds`):

```
/home/user_me/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/DataSpell/ch-0/233.13135.105/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py
```

Here is the help info of DataSpell:

```
DataSpell 2023.3.2
Build #DS-233.13135.105, built on December 21, 2023
Licensed to  
Subscription is active until 
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 17.0.9+7-b1087.9 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-87-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Registry:
  python.scientific.always_use_sci_view=true
  python.scientific.show_help_window=false
  editor.minimap.enabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.github.copilot (1.4.8.4188)
  nl.rubensten.texifyidea (0.9.2)
Current Desktop: X-Cinnamon
```

Here is the help info of PyCharm:

```
PyCharm 2023.3.2 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-233.13135.95, built on December 20, 2023
Licensed to 
Subscription is active until 
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 17.0.9+7-b1087.9 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-87-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.github.copilot (1.4.5.4049)
Current Desktop: X-Cinnamon
```

Comment: Weird. I don't see a wrds.py file associated with the wrds 3.1.6. Perhaps the IDE has another wrds package on its path.

Comment: Actually it seems there's never been a `wrds.py` in that package. Nor is there a check `os.name == 'nt'` in the repository history. So maybe a stray `wrds.py` is in the path ahead of `wrds`.

Comment: Thx Ian - interesting to see PyCharm and DataSpell acting differently here.

Answer (score 0):

The magical world of JetBrains: `import wrds` referred to a same-named `wrds.py` file higher up in the project tree.

I removed the `.idea` folder at that higher level and opened the working folder at the proper level of my project tree.